# Opencv C++ finding movement in a thresholded image

Tags: c++, .net, opencv, image-processing, motion-detection

I am using openCv with C++ and I am trying to find a moving ball under different lighting conditions. So far I am able to filter an image by thresholding it using HSV color space. The problem with this is that it will pick up other object that have a similar color. It is very tedious to figure out the exact hsv range everytime there is a ball with different color/background.

Is there a way for me to apply any filter on the thresholded binary image to detect only the objects that are moving? This way I will only find the ball and not other objects since they are usually stationary.

Thank you,

Varun

Comment: Is it a still snapshot of a moving ball or is it moving from one frame to the next frame of that image?

Comment: It will be moving from one frame to the next frame. I am doing this on a webcam feed. 

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach would be frame differencing / background learning in an image sequence.

- frame differencing: substract two successive frames, the result is the moving part (you will probably only get the edges of moving objects)
- background learning: e.g. build an average over 50 frames, this would be your learned background, then substract the current frame, again the difference is the moving part

Comment: I looked around for this and I understand the concept but I am having hard time implementing this in c++. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What's the exact problem? As it seems you are already familiar with opencv.

Comment: A much delayed response, but this did help me figure out the problem after. I just had to read up a little more. Thanks